# Bootable USB doesn't show up on the start of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, usb

As you can see the bootable USB is being auto detected. When I keep the USB inserted and restart the laptop, the USB booting option doesn't show up.

What information do I need to present here in order for you to help me?

Default OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Laptop: DELL

```
BIOS Setup -> Boot Options ->   
Boot Mode  
Boot Mode UEFI Only

Boot sequence:

(tick marked in this order)  

ubuntu  
UEFI SSD 128GB <a long number>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (removable USB not shown at boot). The solution was the priority order among SATA devices (the external USB may be allocated as SATA in the BIOS device list). Putting USB as first in the list solved the problem.